# Expected Minimum Distance between draws of rv

Tags: probability, probability-theory, concentration-of-measure

If $X$ is a random variable, then Chebyshev's inequality states that $$\Pr(|X-E(X)|\ge t)\le\frac{Var(X)}{t^2}.$$ If the "spread"/variance of the distribution $X$ is drawn from is very large, then for small $t$ this inequality gives no useful information. My question is if we get several draws from $X$, can we say something a bit stronger, something like this:

If $X_1,\ldots, X_N, X_{N+1}$ are iid, then can we bound $\Pr(\min_{1\le i\le N} |X_i - X_{N+1}| \ge t)?$ It seems like we should be able to say that this would be small with much higher confidence than in the vanilla Chebyshev, since the $N$ samples we draw before comparing the distance to $X_{N+1}$ intuitively seems to capture the spread of the distribution, and would potentially yield a better concentration than comparing to the mean. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Note that the $E(X)$ and $\text{Var}(X)$ in Chebyshev's inequality are population parameters not sample statistics.  Which population parameters were you thinking about using for your later version?

Comment: I would think Var(X), since you would expect that the higher the variance is, the more samples you need for the confidence bound on the probability i wrote to be small.

Answer (score 2):

Since $X_{N+1}$ is independent of the vector $\left(X_1,\dots,X_N\right)$, it follows (from Fubini's theorem) that 
$$
\Pr\left(\min_{1\le i\le N} |X_i - X_{N+1}| \ge t\right)=\int_{\mathbb R}\Pr\left(\min_{1\le i\le N} |X_i - x| \ge t\right)\mathrm{d}{\Pr}_{X_{N+1}}(x).
$$
Using independence of the vector $\left(X_1,\dots,X_N\right)$ and then the fact that all the components have the same distribution, we get that 
$$
\Pr\left(\min_{1\le i\le N} |X_i - x| \ge t\right)=\prod_{i=1}^n\Pr\left(\left\lvert X_i-x \right\rvert \geq t\right)=\Pr\left(\left\lvert X_1-x \right\rvert \geq t\right)^N
$$
hence 
$$
\Pr\left(\min_{1\le i\le N} |X_i - X_{N+1}| \ge t\right)=\int_{\mathbb R}\Pr\left(\left\lvert X_1-x \right\rvert \geq t\right)^N\mathrm{d}{\Pr}_{X_{N+1}}(x).
$$